# Programming safe/regular/atomic registers with Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My question relates to the "Art of Multiprocessor Programming" book. The chapter 4 is about safe/regular/atomic registers and their implementations.

There is the following implementation of Safe Multiple-Readers Single-Writer Boolean register, which is based on Safe Single-Reader Single-Writer register, considered to be "available".

```
public class SafeBooleanMRSWRegister implements Register<Boolean> {
 boolean[] s_table; // array of safe SRSW registers
 public SafeBooleanMRSWRegister(int capacity) {
    s_table = new boolean[capacity];
 }
 public Boolean read() {
    return s_table[ThreadID.get()];
 }
 public void write(Boolean x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s_table.length; i++)
       s_table[i] = x;
 }
```

The questions are:

1) Where this mysterious Single-Reader Single-Writer resides? There is no implementation in the book.

2) Why we need this array-based implementation of MRSW register? Why usual SRSW fails? Why this array guarantees something - because we suppose if two threads start writing they will write to each SRSW separately because of that cycle? But in Java it is not guaranteed.

3) This register is considered to be safe, and not regular. Why not regular? How can we see any values, different from the previous and ongoing writes?

4) Safe, regular or atomic registers should always return the last written value if there is no overlapping of read/write calls. But in the code samples from this book this never fulfils because in Java we need a memory barrier to guarantee this.
And if we use 'volatile' keyword for the register's field, then, as far as I understand, it becomes atomic for all the field types except for long and double, including arbitrary user types. So with volatile magic we dont need this code at all.

May be I am just missing the whole point and this examples are not the real code but some ideas of how the hardware works?

Comment: Java's JVM is supposed to shield you from such processor specific details.    It looks like that missing class is part of this book's implementation: http://www.uiowa.edu/hri/courses/multicoreProgramming/Morgan.Kaufmann.The.Art.of.Multiprocessor.Programming.Mar.2008.eBook-BBL/Multiprocessor%20Programming.PDF

Comment: Yes, this is a book I am talking about. There is no such a class. This looks like abstraction or something I dont get.

Comment: NO, there's got to be a link where you can go to get code downloads.  None of the examples will even compile without it.  Got to be something concrete for readers to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part I of that book (includes chapter 4) is mostly theory.  When he says, "register", he is talking about a mathematical abstraction that corresponds, more or less, to how memory works on most computer systems.  The chapter in question attempts to mathematically prove what are the *least* guarantees that multi-processor hardware must provide, in order for us to construct provably-correct, multi-threaded software systems.

The terms "safe", and "regular", and "register" each have a very specific, mathematical meaning where they are used in that chapter.  The meanings are all explained in the text.  You'll just have to read it carefully, and maybe try to work through some of the exercises.

Don't expect everything that you read about in Part I to be something that you can implement in Java, and don't expect *anything* in Part I to be something that you would want to use in a real program.  Part II is where you start to find the practical applications of the theory that Part I describes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Where this mysterious Single-Reader Single-Writer resides? There is no implementation in the book.

Consider safe SRSW just as basic building block. It provides the weakest gurantees.

2. Why we need this array-based implementation of MRSW register? Why usual SRSW fails?

Because SRSW provides no gurantees when is read by multiple readers. It's just "undefined behaviour".

3. This register is considered to be safe, and not regular. Why not regular? How can we see any values, different from the previous and ongoing writes?

Consider write(true) followed by another write(true) overlapping with read(). Regular register read should return true. Safe register may return any value from the range - true or false. That's why in regular register construction we do not perform write if same value is already in this register.

4. Safe, regular or atomic registers should always return the last written value if there is no overlapping of read/write calls. But in the code samples from this book this never fulfils because in Java we need a memory barrier to guarantee this.

Yes, this is just the theory.